# Remove NULL values and corresponding column names from SQL Insert statements

Tags: sql, null

I very frequently have to deal with sql written by others.
A typical sql insert statements can hold 5-6 uneeded values (NULL).

An example:

```
INSERT INTO Texts (Text_EN, Text_NO, Text_DK, Text_SV) VALUES ('English', NULL, NULL, 'Svenska')
```

I've been looking for a way to transform a line like this into:

```
INSERT INTO Texts (Text_EN, Text_SV) VALUES ('English', 'Svenska')
```

So what I want to accomplish is:

- Find the NULL values
- Find the columns that correspond to those values
- Remove those values and the column names

I've been trying various regexes with positive lookbehinds, since I think I'd need to find the NULLs first, but no dice. Perhaps there's another way already?

I've been checking out sql formatters as well, but they doesn't seem to have this very specific functionality.

Comment: I don't think this can be done using regular expressions.

Comment: Why do you need to do this?

Comment: Because the extra values and columns that's not needed just adds up to line noise, and I have to deal with a lot of very large statements.

Comment: Do you want standard SQL or SQL for a particular RDBMS?

Comment: Well, we're using mysql (mariadb) but I'd think standard sql would be just fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using dynamic SQL. For example, write function for 2 input array type parameters. One of the arrays is for fields and another array for values. Inside the function, you can declare 2 string-type variables, for dynamic SQLs, and use one for-loop operation. In this loop check values by the if operation. If the value is null then don't add to string values and fields, if-else add. After the loop is set to your main string variable 'insert into table' then execute dynamic SQL.
Shortly example:

```
declare 
    v_sql varchar(1000);
    v_fields  varchar(1000);
    v_valuesm  varchar(1000);
begin 
    -- for-loop statement 
    -- if check generate striong variables for fiedls and values 
    -- end of for-loop statement 
    v_sql = 'INSERT INTO Texts (' + v_fields + ') VALUES (' + v_values + ')';
    -- executing your v_sql
```